# Input field keeps switching between text and date in ASP.NET Core MVC application

Tags: model-view-controller, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having a problem with an input field switching between type=text (when it's not focused) and type=date (when it's focused). I'm using .NET Core 3.1 framework.

Model:

```
public class DocumentVersionModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DocumentModelId { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage="Date only")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage="Date only")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime LastChangeDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage="Date only")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DocumentDate { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
    public DocumentModel Document { get; set; }
}
```

The format `yyyy-MM-dd` is needed for the database and is the one displayed when the input field isn't focused. The format I need to display the dates is `mm/dd/yyyy`, but I can't change the `DateFormatString` (and removing `ApplyFormatInEditMode = true` didn't work).

This is the form in the RazorPage:

```
<form asp-action="Edit">
<br />
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-12 form-group">
        <label>Titolo</label>
        <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" id="iddoc" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Data Documento</label>
            <input asp-for="DocumentVersion.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Version==Model.ActiveVersion).DocumentDate" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="DocumentVersion.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Version==Model.ActiveVersion).DocumentDate" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Data Creazione</label>
            <input asp-for="DocumentVersion.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Version==Model.ActiveVersion).CreationDate" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Data Ultima Modifica</label>
            <input asp-for="DocumentVersion.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Version==Model.ActiveVersion).LastChangeDate" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

A little note about the form: if I use `type="date"` or `"datetime"` inside the input tag, the type keeps changing between text and date, but if I use `"datetime-local"` is shown correctly (but it displays the time too which I don't need).

This is the GIF of what happens:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzQaS.jpg

This is the very bad and inefficient jQuery solution I used to "fix" the problem:

```
$('#DocumentDate, #LastChangeDate, #CreationDate').attr('type','date'); //when the page loads
    $(document).click(function () {
        if ($('#DocumentDate').not(':focus') || $('#LastChangeDate').not(':focus') || $('#CreationDate').not(':focus'))
            $('#DocumentDate, #LastChangeDate, #CreationDate').attr('type','date');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So what is your current problem? Do you not want to use jquery to
>   achieve it?

I think the method you are using by jquery is implemented very well because **you cannot change the date type input control to display the date format you want**: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519493/12884742).

**Another solution is to use Datepicker plugin for jquery UI**, but this cannot avoid using jquery.

Here is the example based jquery UI Datepicker :

```
@model WebApplication_core_mvc.Models.DocumentVersionModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "DateEdit";
} 
<h1>DateEdit</h1>
@section Scripts{ 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script> 
        $(function () { // will trigger when the document is ready
            $('.datepicker').datepicker();
            $('.datepicker').datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "mm/dd/yy"); //Initialise any date pickers
        });
    </script>
}

<form asp-action="Edit">
    <br />
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12 form-group">
            <label>Titolo</label>
            <input asp-for="DocumentModelId" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" id="iddoc" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Data Documento</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CreationDate, new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
                <span asp-validation-for="CreationDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Data Creazione</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastChangeDate, new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Data Ultima Modifica</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DocumentDate, new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, in the meantime I found out that an MDBootstrap function inside free-form is what causes the trouble with the dates... I'll try to see if by deleting the files that use that function will solve the problem, otherwise I'll try your solution :)

Comment: I noticed now a problem: the date shows the hours, minutes and seconds too. How can I avoid this?

Comment: @n00bCod3r,  In fact, you should notice the second statement I wrote in the jquery method, `$('.datepicker').datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "mm/dd/yy");` .Here you can set the date format displayed, such as "mm/dd/yy" that I set here.

Comment: I think I finally solved by using:
`<input value="@documentVersion.DocumentDate.ToShortDateString()" type="text" id="DocumentDate" readonly class="form-control datepicker white" /> `(documentVersion is passed to this cshtml using the ViewBag